# Root pointer of linked list keeps varying when passed to a function in header file, How to keep it constant?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I've created a header file with some basic linked list functions, one of them is append(), which takes a struct node* pointer and value as argument.
so when I call the function, for some reason the root value gets changed, so I had to keep passing the root pointer from the called and main.
Is their a way to correct this?

**what I've tried : **

**main source code : **

```
#include"singly_linked_list0.h"

struct node* root = NULL;

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    while(n > 0){
        root = append(root, n);
        n--;
    }
    print_all(root);

    return 0;
}
```

** header function : **

```
/*appends the value passed at the end, and returns the ROOT*/
struct node* append(struct node* ROOT, int d){
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = d;
    temp->link = NULL;
    if(ROOT == NULL) ROOT = temp;
    else{
        struct node *p;
        p = ROOT;
        while(p->link != NULL){
            p = p->link;
        }
        p->link = temp;
    }

    return ROOT;
}
```

Comment: header files should not contain any code.

Comment: Is this the code that "keep passing the root pointer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a pointer to the root pointer to your `append` function:

```c
void append(struct node **ROOT, int d){
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    // Check whether malloc was successful. Otherwise, exit with error
    if (temp == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    temp->data = d;
    temp->link = NULL;

    // If there is no root node yet, this can be set directly
    if (*ROOT == NULL)
        *ROOT = temp;
    // Otherwise, it is not touched
    else {
        struct node *p = *ROOT;
        while(p->link != NULL){
            p = p->link;
        }
        p->link = temp;
    }
}
```

It's then called via `append(&root, n)`.

**Credit:** As P__J__ mentioned there were some other issues in the code that are fixed here.

Comment: three issues: 1. casting of the result of malloc 2. No malloc result test 3. sizeof type

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node {int d; struct node *link;} *root = NULL;

struct node* append(struct node* ROOT, int d)
{
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));

    if(newnode)
    {
        newnode -> d = d;
        newnode -> link = NULL;
        if(ROOT)
        {
            struct node *list = ROOT;
            while(list -> link) list = list -> link;
            list -> link = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            ROOT = newnode;
        }
    }
    return newnode ? ROOT : newnode;
}

void printall(struct node *ROOT)
{
    while(ROOT)
    {
        printf("Node d = %d\n", ROOT -> d);
        ROOT = ROOT -> link;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    while(n > 0)
    {
        struct node *newroot = append(root, n);
        if(newroot) root = newroot;
        else printf("ERROR at n = %d\n", n);
        n--;
    }
    printall(root);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jPnhKE